# webpack how to define every source file name

Tags: javascript, webpack

webpack actual output single file `bundle.js`, but developer can see the source filenames in chrome console, How it work?

#### The source code:

a.js

```
import './b.js'
console.log('hello from a.js')
```

b.js

```
console.log('hello from b.js')
```

#### In chrome console:

[image: in chrome console]

What API can show the source file name ?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack actually outputs a second file when you are building in development mode. This is a sourcemap file which lets the browser know where to find the correct source files. In your case this is probably called `bundle.js.map`.

In production people usually don't publish the sourcemap file.

For more details on how it works there are many articles online, heres a few:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps

Heres how to do sourcemaps in webpack:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: thanks buddy, this is sourceURL implementation, dose need enable sourceMap. found in https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps#sourceurl_displayname

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Luke help me found the sourceURL: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps#sourceurl_displayname

In `bundle.js`, I found

```
eval("console.log('hello from b.js')\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./b.js?");
```

The last comment `//# sourceURL=` specifies the source file name.